# How many pieces of lumber do I need to make a box?

Tags: optimization, word-problem

I've started building raised gardens boxes of custom sizes.

[image: raised garden box drawing]

For a given box of width $x$ and length $y$, how many boards of lumber of length $l$ do I need to build this box?

- Assume (for now) the sides of the box are lines. Do not worry about the width of the boards. This also means height is irrelevant. Assume that I buy boards that are always tall enough. This should be treated as a 1-dimensional problem.
- The remainder cut from a side can be used to construct other sides! This is where I'm getting hung up. For example, if $l = 8$, I can make sides of length (4 and 4), (5 and 3), or even (2 and 2 and 2 and 2), etc.
- I **cannot mend** boards together to make a side. (Practically, it's not as strong as single piece, which is important when you're holding in hundreds of pounds of soil.) This scenario would require a new board of lumber.
- Assume that $l \ge \max(x, y)$. In other words, my boards are always long enough to build a side with just 1 board.

Bonus!: In reality, the boards do have a width, say $w$. Therefore, 2 of the sides should take into account the [butt joint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butt_joint) from the other sides.  For example, in my picture, the $x$ sides actually only require a cut of length $x - 2w$. How would the formula change in this case?

([Photo gallery of one bed I built](https://photos.app.goo.gl/EKFYjBmTzVeBa6D67) )

Comment: This is actually a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem), not a geometric one.  This means that the best way to solve this in practice, is to write a small program, say in Python (command-line) or in Javascript (web page), that you tell $x$, $y$, and $l$, and it will find the optimal solution, and tell you how to cut the boards.  Because computers are fast, you don't even need real "math" for it, just brute-force check each possible way, and return the one with the fewest boards (but longest offcuts among the same number of boards needed), for example.

Comment: @None:  this is actually called the stock cutting problem, which is similar to packing and also hard.  For small numbers of pieces it is usually obvious what you want to do.  Usually you are given the length and asked to find the optimal way to allocate the pieces to minimize the number of lengths required.

Answer (score 0):

If $x,y$ are the interior measurements of the box you need  a total length of $2x+2y-4w$
This can all come from one board of that length, with two pieces $y$ and two pieces $x-2w$
They can come from two boards of length $y+x-2w$ with each cut once.
They can come from three boards of length $\max(y,2x-4w)$
They can come from four boards of length $y$.

You start by asking how long the boards have to be, but then talk about what you can do from a given length.  Which direction do you want to go?  By making the joints differently you can use boards of length $y-2w$ and $x$, which may help.  You could also use boards $y-w, x-w$ if that helps.  You also do not talk about making multiple boxes, which raises more possibilities.

Comment: Great points and insights. Regarding the joints, I did some experimentation on how to make them to optimize for maximal inside area; presumably, this is what gardeners would want. [Here's a drawing of some of the ways](https://i.imgur.com/yPLiOU6.png). It seems the best is to have the short side end butt against the long side.

Comment: I hesitate to accept this answer because it does not take $l$ as an input. In my case, I only have access to 8ft long boards, for example. But I also think I did not accurately convey the problem. You commented above about this being the stock cutting problem, which I think is the most helpful. I did whip up a brute force Python solver (and it is super slow).

Comment: You can just go down the list to find the first one that works with length $l$.  It wasn't clear to me whether you knew $l$ and wanted to know what boxes you can build or know $x,y$ and want to know how many boards to buy.